# Error in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange

Hi I am trying hard to write a stored procedure in ISeries DB2 but having errors.

```
  create procedure pakretst.fttest2
(IN fExpression CHARACTER(10))

language sql

reads sql data

dynamic result sets 1

begin

declare stmt VARCHAR(50);

declare x cursor for sl;

If ftExpression IS NOT NULL

 set stmt='select * from pakretst.uwftrtystp WHERE'+ftExpression;

else


 set stmt='select * from pakretst.uwftrtystp';

prepare sl from stmt;

open x;

return;

end

;
```

****SQL State: 42618
Vendor Code: -312
Message: [SQL0312] Variable FTEXPRESSION not defined or not usable. Cause . . . . . :   The variable FTEXPRESSION appears in the SQL statement, but one of the following conditions exists: -- No declaration for the variable exists. --**

Comment: It says something about variable not found which I am including in input variable, description added in original post.

Comment: When something like this doesn't make sense, let your computer help. Copy the variable name from the error message and use your PC's "Search" feature to find it in the source text. **Do not** simply try to do all checking with your eyes. They are what failed you in this example question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a simple error in transcription, but in what you given here, you have

```
(IN fExpression CHARACTER(10))
```

in the parameter list but

```
set stmt='select * from pakretst.uwftrtystp WHERE'+ftExpression;
```

at the point of usage - `fExpression` versus `ftExpression`...

Comment: thanks, can't believe I did that. Although it throws another error now but its a move forward.

Cheers.